# how to change inputs borders if the password do not match in javascript

Tags: javascript

> I used `If_statment` in my code with two conditions, first one the input should be `not empty`, second condition the password should be `incorrect` to excute the code. but the code excuted anyway even the password is correct

```
 <form> 
  <label for="password">password : </label>
  <input type="text" name="password" value="" id="password" /> 
  <label for="confirmation">Confirm : </label>
  <input type="text" name="confirmation" value="" id="confirmation" /> 
  <button type="button" name="button" >Test</button> 
 </form>

 var password = document.querySelector("#password");
 var confirm = document.querySelector("#confirmation");
 var button = document.querySelector("button");
 var pass_value = password.value;

 var change_border = function() {

 if(pass_value !== null || pass_value !== "s1234") {
    password.style.border = "3px solid gray";
    confirm.style.border = "3px solid gray";
   }
  }
 button.addEventListener("click", change_border);
```

Comment: Can you add HTML code?. You could be using an incorrect event

Comment: submit button emits submit event when you use a form element. It could be

Comment: you could add form.addEventListener("submit", function(e){ e.preventDefault() })

Comment: Add extra provided code to the question instead of as a comment. It cannot receive proper formatting as a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you get `pass_value` before `change_border` function execution, so the value will be empty.

Second, you should use `&&` to compare `pass_value` instead of `||`

```js
var confirm = document.querySelector("#confirmation");
var button = document.querySelector("button");
 
var change_border = function() {
    var password = document.querySelector("#password");
    var pass_value = password.value;
    if(pass_value !== null && pass_value !== "s1234") {
        password.style.border = "3px solid gray";
        confirm.style.border = "3px solid gray";
    }
}

button.addEventListener("click", change_border);
```

```html
<form> 
  <label for="password">password : </label>
  <input type="text" name="password" value="" id="password" /> 
  <label for="confirmation">Confirm : </label>
  <input type="text" name="confirmation" value="" id="confirmation" /> 
  <button type="button" name="button" >Test</button> 
 </form>
```